# lines terminated by '\n' is not working when moving the data from hive view to a hive external table

Tags: hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I have given the external table creation in hive below

```
create external table tablename (column details)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
location 'location in which the data gets stored'
```

However, after the creation and loading of that external table. I see that the underlying data file in the folder is containing the data in a single line. i.e the newline setting is not working.

I am running the hiveql through Azure hd insight cluster

Comment: Try to add `stored as TextFile` to your query. The problem might by with the default file format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..but that is not solving the problem..I gave stored as TextFile after lines terminated by option..

Comment: How exactly are you checking files? did you try `hadoop fs -text` command?

Comment: The underlying file for the hive external table gets stored in Azure Bob Storage.So, after the external table is loaded, i am going to the folder in which that file is present and opening it with notepad.

Comment: Well the problem is that Windows (and hence notepad) needs CR LF (`\r\n`) as end-of-line instead of single LF (`\n`) as in Unix-like systems. So you need to change `\n` to `\r\n`

Comment: Ran as you said. However, It threw an error saying LINES TERMINATED BY clause only supports \n right now